# How to overlap 2 charaters with CSS

Tags: css

I have 2 Unicode arrows, that I would like to have on top of one another ( eg as a column sorter ).

How can I do this? - a `<br>` tag in a span won't work, as it breaks the entire content flow.

I also cant set `position:absolute` and top 0, left 0, as it needs to be relatively positioned.

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YrJTN/1/

Comment: What are you actually trying to make this look like? "on top of one another" is ambiguous, as reflected in one of the currently deleted answers.

Comment: I am hoping to get sorting arrows ALA http://tablesorter.com/docs/ ( except with unicode instead of images )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use position absolute, just add a container that has position relative
like this:`

```
<span style="position:relative">
    <span style="position: absolute;">▼</span>
    <span style="position: absolute;">▲</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Name<span class="up" style="text-size:50%"></span>
```

Css:

```
.up:before{
    content: "▲";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
.up:after{
    content: "▼";
    position:absolute;
    top: 0.8em;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KqV6A/

Comment: You should set `top` in the `em` unit so that this will work with any font size: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/YrJTN/5/

Comment: and about links in arrows?

Comment: That will be a problem.

Comment: seems obvious to me that arrows should be links. maybe i am wrong.

Comment: As much as I love this solution, linking in the arrows is kinda the point.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <span class="column">
        Name
        <span class="arrow top">&#9650;</span>
        <span class="arrow bottom">&#9660;</span>
    </span>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.column {
    position: relative;
}

.arrow {
    font-size: 10pt;
    position: absolute;    
}
.top {
    right: -10px;
    top: -5px;
}

.bottom {
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of vertical align and negative margins:

HTML:

```
Name<span class="arrows"><a class="up" href="#up">&#9650;</a><a class="down" href="#down">&#9660;</a></span>
```

CSS:

```
.arrows a { display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; width:1em;  }
.arrows a + a { margin-left:-1em; }
.up { vertical-align:0.4em;  }
.down { vertical-align:-0.4em; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YrJTN/6/

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UHbHt/1/)

```
.fl {
    color: #FCB80D;
    float: right;
}
.wrapper {
    width:60px;
    font-size:12px;
}

<div class="wrapper">text
    <div class="fl"> 
    <a href="#" id="scrollUp">▲</a> <!-- </br> if you want-->
    <a href="#" id="scrollDown">▼</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <body>Name<span style=" position: absolute;text-size:50% ">&#9660;</span><span style=" position: absolute;text-size:50% ">&#9650;</span></body>
```

Comment: Please try to include some kind of explaination with your answer, as well as the actual code.  :)